# Autocomplete associated fields - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

These are the fields I have in my view, the autocomplete on the partcode brings up a list of partcodes from a partcode table. Depending on what partcode is chosen, i want it to dynamically update the description with the description from the partcode table.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label "partcode" %><br />
<%=f.autocomplete_field :partcode, "/goods_ins/1/autocomplete_partcode_partcode" %>
</div>    
<div class="field">
<%= f.label "description" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :description, :autocomplete => :off %>
</div>
```

This is in my routes:

```
resources :goods_ins do
  get :autocomplete_partcode_partcode, :collection => {:view => :get} 
end
```

And my controller:

```
autocomplete  :partcode, :partcode, :extra_data => [:description]
```

Comment: This may be best done using JQuery and defining an `.onChange` event handler on the `partcode` field.

Answer (score 0):

Use following way,

First give id to your text field as below

```
<%= f.text_field :description,:autocomplete=>:off, :id_element=>'#part_desc'%>
```

Now set update_elements property with above element id as below

```
<%=f.autocomplete_field :partcode, "/goods_ins/1/autocomplete_partcode_partcode",:update_elements=>{:id =>'#part_code', :description=>'#part_desc'} %>
```

Comment: Already tried that way, it doesn't error, but it doesn't update anything either :/ !

Comment: Ok.do you get anything into log ? or use firebug .. do you have any webpage link where i can check it ?

Comment: it's only local at the moment so you can't see it i'm afraid, but no i don't get anything in the log either.. sorry !

Comment: You can also use below event as well.        $('#my_autocomplete_field').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
  /* Do something here */
  alert(data.item.id);
});

Comment: i don't understand how/where to put that last bit, i'm new to this!